# How do I train a neural net when I don't know the target?

Tags: neural-network

I'm making a neural network which learns to play flappy bird. The net receives:

1. The distance (x) between the agent and the nearest pipe
2. The distance (y) between the agent and the top of the nearest pipe
3. The distance (y) between the agent and the bottom of the nearest pipe

To train the neural net I need a desired output, which, obviously, is to safely clear the top and bottom of the pipe. However, how do I train the net if I don't know exactly how much the agent has to jump to do so?

I'm new to neural nets, and I've written programs where the net can take a guess and I can compare that guess to the easily-calculatable correct answer, and I can adjust weights from there - in this case, I don't know the right answer, and the point of the net is to figure it out itself.

What can I do to achieve this? Maybe a few links pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Training a traditional feed forward NN with backtracing means you need to have enough training data, with known results. To build a NN that can solve a problem you "don't know" the solution to - you could look at other training solutions. For example, using genetic algorithms you can evolve a NN that "happens to work"; scoring them on how far they get through flappy bird and breeding till you have a "solution".

Comment: Reinforcement-learning.

Comment: As in, generating a significant number of agents at the beginning, and the top 50% scorers reproduce? Do they pass on the same genetic info, or should it mutate? Does this even involve neural nets anymore? @Bilkokuya

Comment: @CasparB Neural nets are just a structure to categorise inputs into outputs - the way you develop it, train it or otherwise construct it doesn't stop it being a neural net (you can for example write one with all the weights chosen by hand - although the likelyhood it will be useful is low). It was just an example that there are many ways to do what you want and to look around for alternatives to backtracing for your training. The suggestion from sascha is a more realistic approach you probably want to actually look at.

Comment: Neural Networks are function-approximators. That's all. As mentioned, you can assign weights how you like it. It's still a NN. I might add: in RL-setting, NNs just replace the action-value function, as our NN now acts as a function-approximation for this (instead of using tables like for example in many toy problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This family of problems is targeted by Reinforcement Learning. In Reinforcement Learning all you need is to pass to the network a reward (the game score) and let the network to estimate effect of each action on the final reward (or to learn Q-table). There is big variety of approaches, but I find following tutorial as a good point to start:

https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0